# How to find exact low voltage and high voltage values?

Tags: comparator, hysteresis

How to find the Hysteresis comparator exact "V high and V low" values
[image]

Comment: Hint: assuming that the output swings between Vcc and Vss, which Vin voltage makes the + input equal to Vref, assuming 1) Vout = Vcc, and 1) assuming Vout = Vss?

Comment: You need to find the DC solution for each case separately: When Vout is high and when it is low. For each one, what is the value of Vin that will cause it to switch to the other state?

Answer (score 1):

An equation in b) is incorrect.

Assuming a single supply where output , Vo, swings rail-to-rail , ground to Vo = Vcc.

VH=Vref * (Rf/R +1)

VL was ok.

VL=Vref-R/Rf*Vo

Thus Vref is always between VL & VH.

The amount (%) of hysteresis = (VH-VL) / Vo  *100, which a bonus ? for you to solve.

Answer (score 0):

As you should know, by voltage division, if the output is currently high, \$V_{OUT} = V_{OH}\$, the voltage on the non-inverting input terminal is

$$V_+ = \frac{V_{IN}R_F + V_{OH}R}{R + R_F}$$

And, if the output is currently low, \$V_{OUT} = V_{OL}\$, the voltage on the non-inverting input terminal is

$$V_+ = \frac{V_{IN}R_F + V_{OL}R}{R + R_F}$$

Can you take it from here?